# Is there are any common pattern/practice to handle exception list (Java)?

Tags: java, exceptions, exception-handling

Suppose I've got a sophisticated parser for something.
And a I don't want Throw Early/Fail-Fast strategy.
If I've got multiple problems, i want to have list of exceptions in my log file
because I want exactly know where cause in source code is.

Comment: Mean what you do by _"where cause in source code is"_?

Comment: To make you think in a different direction: consider [parser combinators](http://theorangeduck.com/page/you-could-have-invented-parser-combinators) and [railway-oriented programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) to avoid exceptions altogether; instead, [collect errors as you go](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/12/23/kleisli-categories/). Sorry, I have nothing to say about the all-important recovery after parsing errors.

Comment: Catch every exception and log them.

Comment: @user61852 `catch(Pikachu e) { ... }`?  At least we know what base type a Charazard is.

Answer (score 8):

Continuing under parse errors can be a bit nontrivial, and simply crying “parser combinator” will not fix that.

The central point is that your parser won't throw exceptions when it encounters syntax errors. Instead, these exceptions are queued in a list until a problem is sufficiently fatal, you have too many problems, or the end of input has been reached.

After you encounter a syntax problem, you have to try to re-sync your parser with the input. For common mistakes, create special productions that match these mistakes. This can be used to create truly helpful error messages, and provides excellent recovery. Errors such as “missing closing paren” or “missing semicolon” can be handled well by this. Just make sure that the error rules have lower precedence than the normal syntax. After an error rule is completed, you can continue with the normal grammar.

However, error rules only handle the minority of issues. In most cases, you will want to skip a part of the input until it is safe to continue. Don't worry about creating an invalid parse tree, since after an error the parse will be discarded. One possibility to recover is to skip until an expected token of a production higher in the parse tree has been found. Consider `foo(1, 2 3) + 4; bar();`. Between `2` and `3` there should have been a comma or a binary operator, we don't know. We do know that we are inside the “function arguments” production, and that the next expected symbol would be a comma or a closing paren. Or we could see that we are in the “statement” production and skip to the next semicolon. In either case, we need to look through the stack of current productions and search for predicted symbols. This may require nontrivial manual adjustments in the case of a top-down parser, but provides really decent error recovery. On the other hand, you might end up skipping a lot of input.

In the worst case, you simply skip the current token and attempt to restart the parse. This may require you to skip multiple tokens until a legal parse appears, and while this method is simple, it should be only used as a last resort.